# Taylor series $ \sqrt{\frac{t}{t+1}}$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, taylor-expansion

Could someone tell me how to calculate 
 $ \sqrt{\frac{t}{t+1}}$

it should be   $ \sqrt t - \frac{t^{\frac{3}{2}}}{2} +O(t^{\frac{5}{2}}) $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{t}{1+t}=t(1-t+t^2-\ldots)\implies\sqrt\frac{t}{1+t}=\sqrt{t\left(1-t+t^2-\ldots\right)}=$$

$$=\sqrt t\,\sqrt{1-t+\ldots}=\sqrt t\left(1-\frac{t}{2}-\frac{t^2}{4}+\ldots\right)=\sqrt t-\frac{t^{3/2}}{2}+\mathcal O(t^{5/2})$$

since

$$\sqrt {1-x}=1+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{1}{4}x^2+\ldots$$

Comment: but I dont know if calculated $\sqrt {1-x}=1+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{1}{4}x^2+\ldots$ if it is good. Maybe $\sqrt {1-x+x^2}$ have factor at $x$

Comment: Just do it, @aiki93:$$\sqrt{1-x+x^2}=\sqrt{1-(x-x^2)}=1+\frac{x-x^2}{2}-\frac{(x-x^2)^2}{4}+\ldots$$Can you see what happens here?

Comment: nice. thanks you

Comment: Might be better to use $1 - t + O(t^2)$ than to keep full precision and write $1 - t + t^2 - \ldots$.

Answer (score 1):

Simple:
$$
\sqrt{\frac{t}{1 + t}} 
   = \sqrt{t} \cdot (1 + t)^{-1/2}
$$
Now use the binomial theorem:
$$
(1 + t)^{-1/2} = \sum_{n \ge 0} \binom{-1/2}{n} t^n
$$
Now:
$$
\binom{-1/2}{n} = (-1)^{n - 1} 2^{-2n} \binom{2n}{n}
$$